# Why is this question closed as not having MCVE, when it has everything?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, minimal-reproducible-example

This question [was closed as not having MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43439229/792066), but does it really needs one, as it "it doesn't have it?".

- Minimal?

  It has the 3 lines of code required to load a torrent and said torrent.
- Complete?

  Yes, it's complete. It has everything needed to arguably reproduce the issue, including the error.
- Verifiable?

  Yep, [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/transmissionrpc/#poking-around) indicates that's the way to load torrents using the RCP python library of transmission. I was able to load a torrent following those steps.

Why was this closed as not having MCVE, when it clearly has all the code needed to reproduce it?

The only information really missing is the torrent that transmission claims that "it's corrupted", which has to be included as external file, since torrent bencoded files aren't very willing to become text only. This is similar to "why my gzip implementation can't unzip this file" just that you aren't the one that created the file but just consume it.

A "invalid or corrupt" torrent file cannot be generated, since:

1. The tool you need to generate it, arguably generates valid torrents, otherwise it would be useless. So that's not an option.
2. Even if you try to modify the file to simulate a corruption... well, obviously it would be corrupted, but it wouldn't tell us why transmission claims that file is corrupted.
3. I'm adding this one, but it's just a modification of 1, if you manage to reliably find a way around the above two, you still would need a file that produces the same hashes that all torrents have, so you would still have "external" dependencies to generate the torrent file.

To top it off, it has some undefined behavior where transmission happily consume the torrent and other times it doesn't. It's the torrent triggering some bug on transmission or something else? Well, we wouldn't know since we can't have the file that produces the error.

Comment: Heh the moderator provided reasoning for why they closed it. If you disagree with that, it's fine and you can include your argument against it, but completely leaving out the fact that you had a conversation with the moderator or any of their reasons is a very misleading question. Why not discuss whether that's valid reasoning instead of trying to Meta-effect the question into an open state?

Comment: @animuson well, he's not providing any "argument" where the question didn't include a MCVE, so isn't only reasonable that said discussion doesn't have any merit?

Comment: You seem to have completely ignored the moderator's point that the torrent linked was a porn video as well. You don't find that relevant?

Comment: @MartinSmith is input metadata, not "porn". Well, lets say its right, and porn is not allowed, how would you reproduce the problem without the file that causes it?

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion given was that an MCVE would use code to generate a suitably minimal torrent file that still exhibited the problem. This is not completely ridiculous on the face of it, although it certainly does pose a serious challenge, as that's likely to be quite difficult to manage for almost any questioner, and probably take a fair amount of effort even if it's practical.

On the other hand, it's also true that a question that inherently cannot exist in any meaningful way without a specific, probably-volatile external link is extremely problematic for SO's basic mission of being a self-contained, reformattable, reusable library.

So you end up with the basic question: is there any reason to override SO's general mission for this particular case where generating MCVEs is highly challenging? Honestly, no, there probably isn't. If it's really hard to get an MCVE, maybe SO isn't really a good place for that kind of question. Irritating, but a fairly similar thing happened with software recommendations, where they *could* have been on-topic, but SO simply wasn't equipped to handle them right and so made them off-topic.

Basically, if SO's quality standards combine together naturally so that a particular group of questions that people will naturally tend to ask on SO becomes essentially impossible to keep open, well, them's the breaks. It's not as though you can just *ignore* the reasons for avoiding reliance on off-site references when they become inconvenient to a particular question, because they still logically apply even when that makes the standards really tough to meet, for the same reasons they apply at all, ever.

Comment: "The suggestion given was that an MCVE would use code to generate a suitably minimal torrent file that still exhibited the problem" Under what circumstance you see that the problem is "generating" a corrupted torrent file possible? Don't you see that OP is saying "After that I stopped the transmission-daemon service, launched it from the console and the result was fine." Care to explain how could someone craft said torrent? That sometimes makes transmission complain that is corrupt and other times don't?

Comment: @Braiam: If it can't be done at all, what's the point of asking on SO about something that simply can't be reproduced?